# Как правильно согласовать?

Tags: согласование

Как согласовать правильно: "42 мужчин"  или "42 мужчины"? "32 женщины" или "32 женщин"?

Answer (score 1):

42 мужчины, 32 женщины.

Можно сказать даже "два мужчины", хотя многие настороженно относятся к этой форме, избегая её и предпочитая ей форму "двое мужчин".

Answer (score 1):

С числительными 2, 3, 4  употребляются существительные родительного падежа единственного  числа: два котенка, двадцать две коровы, тридцать два зуба.
С числительными 5, 6, 7.. употребляются существительные родительного падежа во  множественном  числе: пять яблок, двадцать шесть бакинских  комиссаров, тридцать семь лет.